# How to extract data inside a JSONObject to EditText fields

Tags: java, android, json

In the below shown code, profile contains all the data in the user profile like fname, lname and email (in jsonObject format).I want to extract those details and fill the below shown EditText boxes.

Once I open this form those details will be auto filled to those EditText fields.

```
String profile = getIntent().getStringExtra("profile");
try {
    JSONObject profileJSON = new JSONObject(profile);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
fnameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerfName);
lnameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerlName);
emailET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Just extract data from `JSONObject` and used `edit_text.setText(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JSONObject.getString(key)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29) to get all values using keys from JSONObejct:

```
JSONObject profileJSON = new JSONObject(profile);
fnameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerfName);
fnameET.setText(profileJSON.getString("fname"));
//.... do same to get otger values from profileJSON
```

Also add `null` or `empty` check for values retrieved from `JSONObject` before passing to `setText` method

Answer (score 2):

Do like this

```
fnameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerfName);
lnameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerlName);
emailET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
String profile = getIntent().getStringExtra("profile");
try {
    JSONObject profileJSON = new JSONObject(profile);
    if(profileJSON.has("fname"))
        fnameET.setText(profileJSON.getString("fname"));
    if(profileJSON.has("lname"))
        lnameET.setText(profileJSON.getString("lname"));
    if(profileJSON.has("email"))
        emailET.setText(profileJSON.getString("email"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Comment: Its recommended to use `optString()` because it returns `Empty String` if the key you specified does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(profileJSON!=null){

String userFirstName,userLastName,userEmail;

userFirstName = profileJSON.getString("fname");

userLastName = profileJSON.getString("lname");

userEmail = profileJSON.getString("email");

if(userFirstName!=null){
fnameET.setText(userFirstName);
}

if(userLastName!=null){
 lnameET.setText(userLastName);

}

if(userEmail!=null){
emailET.setText(userEmail);
}



}
```